# iPhone Method Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a method that will analyze if a sound is above a certain decibel level, and if it is then do an action.  I currently am currently calling this method as such

```
- (void) listen { .... }
```

The problem is that, I want the program to constantly be listen for noise, if the user choses to, not just when I call the method.  Should I just hide a button in the background, and just leave it on, or is there an easier and more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always initialize a NSTimer to constantly trigger that check for you...

The `timerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats:` method allows you to run it constantly.

Comment: [NSTimer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)